# Implement a virtual function for two derived classes, that is the same except for one variable Type

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `Node` that can either be a `Leaf` or a `NonLeaf`. I have written a large function `SplitNode`. The problem is, this function is basically the same for a `Leaf` as for a `NonLeaf`. The only difference being that it operates on the `entries` vector for `Leaf`s, as opposed to the `children` vector, for `NonLeaf`s. The code is otherwise identical in both cases. For example in one case I do `entries[i]->r` to access some `Rectangle` property, and in the other case I do `children[i]->r`. So the main difference beyond the 2 variable names, is the type of the actual vector. How am I supposed to implement this, without copying and pasting the same function, implemented slightly differently for `Leaf` and `NonLeaf`?

*Edit:* I also want the `SplitNode` function to be able to be called recursively.

```
class Leaf;
class Node
{
public:
    Node();
    virtual Leaf& ChooseLeaf(const Rectangle& entry_r) = 0;   // this makes the Node class Abstract
    Rectangle r;
    unique_ptr<Node> parent;
};

class Leaf : public Node
{
public:
    Leaf();
    Leaf& ChooseLeaf(const Rectangle& entry_r) override;
    vector<unique_ptr<IndexEntry>> entries;
};

class NonLeaf : public Node
{
public:
    NonLeaf();
    Leaf& ChooseLeaf(const Rectangle& entry_r) override;
    vector<unique_ptr<Node>> children;
};
```

Dummy illustration of the `SplitNode()` function:

```
void SplitNode()
{
    // in the Leaf case:
    if (this.entries.size() > rtree.M)
    { ... } 
    
    // in the NonLeaf case:
    if (children.size() > rtree.M)
    { ... }         
    
    // in the Leaf case:
    entries[0]->r.DoSomething();
    
    // in the NonLeaf case:
    children[0]->r.DoSomething();

    // Recursion
    parent.SplitNode();
    
    ...
|
```

Comment: Do you know what template functions are, and how to use them?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have been trying to implement some sort of a `template` idea. One of the problems that seems to appear is that abstract classes don't seem particularly compatible with templates. So, if you have any detailed idea of how that works let me know.

Comment: How about something like `virtual Rectangle& getChildrenRectangle(int index);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a textbook case for a template function. Presuming that the common logic freestanding logic whose only dependency is the vector itself:

```
template<typename T>
void doSplitNode(T &entries_or_children)
{
   for (auto &entry_or_child:entries_or_children)
   {
      auto &the_r=entry_or_child->the_r;

      // Here's your entries[i]->r, or children[i]->r
   }
}

// ...

class Leaf : public Node
{
public:

    // ...
    void SplitNode()
    {
       doSplitNode(entries);
    }
};

class NonLeaf : public Node
{
    // ...
    void SplitNode()
    {
       doSplitNode(children);
    }
};
```

Additional work will be needed of the shared logic has additional dependencies. There's no universal solution here, everything depends on the details. Perhaps the template itself can be moved into a class, with both `NonLeaf` and `Leaf` multiply-inheriting from it, and then implementing the additional dependencies as virtual/abstract methods.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. But, an issue that I can't solve with your approach, which I probably don't make obvious in my question, is that I don't think I can call `doSplitNode()` recursively. I can call `doSplitNode()` once for example. But then, inside that function's code, how would I call it recursively? The function argument is sometimes `entries` and sometimes `children`. It depends on the instantiation of the object itself. I have an abstract class for this reason.

Comment: How can it be "sometimes" this or the other, if `Leaf` and `NonLeaf` only has one or the other? It is completely unclear what recursion has anything to do with this.

Comment: If you look how I have implemented the `ChooseLeaf` function, I am looking for something similar for a `SplitNode` function. The issue that I have is, if I follow the logic I followed for `ChooseLeaf`, aka make 2 different implementations, then I end up with two large chunks of the same exact code twice, with the only difference in the codes being `entries` vs `children`. And I am looking for solutions to somehow merge them. But I am not seeing how that can be done.

Comment: I can put your `doSplitNode()` function inside my `Node` class, and call it once from some main method. But then, how would this be calling itself recursively? The `Node` class has no access to the `entries` or `children` properties of the derived classes.

Comment: Did you happen to notice that `doSplitNode()` gets the vector's parameter passed in? Your original description was "The code is otherwise identical in both cases ... The only difference being that it operates on the entries vector for Leafs, as opposed to the children vector, for NonLeafs." Making it a template function, and passing in the vector as the templated parameter, addresses that. The End. What recursion has anything to do with anything, here, is completely unclear.

Comment: I updated my code a bit by adding a `parent` pointer. The function `SplitNode()` I want to create, needs to be able to be called recursively. For example, inside it, you should be able to call `parent->SplitNode()`. This is possible for instance in my `ChooseLeaf()` because it is pure virtual. Your function is not pure virtual, and it couldn't be, because its a template.

Comment: The only change that seems necessary is to pass a 2nd parameter, `parent`, in addition to the vector, to `doSplitNode`, from the two `SplitNode`s. Or, if `doSplitNode()` gets implemented as a template function in `Node` (instead of as an ordinary, non-class function), and invoked from one of its subclasses, it can access the `parent` directly, as a member of its class. This still does not change the core of the answer: if the two `SplitNode` are identical, as claimed, except for the vector parameter, then passing the vector as a templated parameter is the answer.